# How to remove exceeding shape in CustomPaint?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to draw a half circle in a rectangle in flutter like this.

[image]

But in my code, the Circle exceeds the white rectangle onto the black background like this

[image]

What changes should I make to the code to get the result like the first pic?

My code:-

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
          child: Scaffold(  
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            body: Center(  
              child: Container(  
                height: 200,
                width: 200,

                color: Colors.white,
                child: CustomPaint(
                  painter: Circ(),
                    child: Column(  
                    children: <Widget>[

                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              
              ),
            ),
          )
    ),
    );
  }
}

class Circ extends CustomPainter{
  
  @override 
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint();
    
    
    
    paint.color = Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2);
    
    var center1 = Offset(200,100);
    
    canvas.drawCircle(center1,100, paint); 

    
  }

    @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems your circle is drawn outside the area you want to confine your painting to.

If you want to paint only in a specified part of the canvas, that is called "clipping".

Add the clipping:

```
canvas.clipRect(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, size.width, size.height));

canvas.drawCircle(center1, 100, paint);
```

This way your circle will not be painted outside the given size.